# Time Ago function not returning correct value

Tags: php, mysqli

i am really having a problem implementing a TIME AGO date. The code i have either displays "2 years ago"... if i try to add a timestamp from my database, it throws me a "46 years ago. I am really lost here. i have been using "new DateTime();", time(), date(), nothing is working. either string expects to be object, incorrect variables, etc... .
Here is the code...

```
<?php
function timeAgo($time_ago){
$cur_time   = time();
$time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
$seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
$minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
$years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
// Seconds
if($seconds <= 60){
    echo "$seconds seconds ago";
}
//Minutes
else if($minutes <=60){
    if($minutes==1){
        echo "one minute ago";
    }
    else{
        echo "$minutes minutes ago";
    }
}
//Hours
else if($hours <=24){
    if($hours==1){
        echo "an hour ago";
    }else{
        echo "$hours hours ago";
    }
}
//Days
else if($days <= 7){
    if($days==1){
        echo "yesterday";
    }else{
        echo "$days days ago";
    }
}
//Weeks
else if($weeks <= 4.3){
    if($weeks==1){
        echo "a week ago";
    }else{
        echo "$weeks weeks ago";
    }
}
//Months
else if($months <=12){
    if($months==1){
        echo "a month ago";
    }else{
        echo "$months months ago";
    }
}
//Years
else{
    if($years==1){
        echo "one year ago";
    }else{
        echo "$years years ago";
    }
}
}

?>
```

The call is...

```
<?php
  $curenttime="2013-07-10 09:09:09";
  $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
  echo timeAgo($time_ago);
?>
```

My SQL string for the timestamp is `$r->time`

Any help would be useful. The code will be used in a Radio Request page at http://autodude666.com/network . 
Much Thanks ahead of time

database Query...

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
require '../db/connect_guest.php';
require '../db/security.php';


$records = array();

if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM guests ORDER BY id DESC")){

    if($results->num_rows){
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
            $records[] = $row;

        }

        $results->free();
    }
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($records), '</pre>';


?>
```

Database insert is....

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])){

        $name       = trim($_POST['name']);
        $email      = trim($_POST['email']);
        $message    = trim($_POST['message']);

        $time       = date("g:i A");
        $date       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  


        if(!empty($name) && !empty($message)){
            $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO guests (name, email, message, date, time, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $insert->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $email, $message, $time, $date, $ip);

            if($insert->execute()){
                header('location: index_input.php');
                die();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Judging by your code, I would expect it to say 2 years ago wouldn't you?  46 years ago tells me that it's going the other direction -- remember that the earliest date of a UNIX timestamp is the epoch (January 1 1970 at 00:00:00).  So, depending on your code, your server's timezone setting, and how the rounding is actually working, that is approximately 46 years ago.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print_r($records)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function timeAgo($time_ago){
    $cur_time   = new DateTime("now");
    $time_ago = new DateTime($time_ago);


    $time_elapsed   = $cur_time->diff($time_ago, true);

    $seconds    = $time_elapsed->s;
    $minutes    = $time_elapsed->i;
    $hours      = $time_elapsed->h;
    $days       = $time_elapsed->d;
    // $weeks      =  diff function doesn't give weeks in the object.
    $months     = $time_elapsed->m;
    $years      = $time_elapsed->y


    echo $years." years, ".$months." months, ".$days." days and ".$hours." hours ".$minutes." minutes and ".$seconds." seconds ago.";

}

?>
```

And play with it from there...

A few other side notes:

In your database insert you have `if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message']))`

Post will send an empty field (i.e. if they don't fill in name or email) as a blank string, which isset will evaluate as true (it is set as a blank string.)  That means these will ALWAYS be true, so it's a worthless test.  Use empty instead.

`if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {`

You could also consolidate your database table columns of time and date into a single column by using a timestamp, and then convert it into whatever format you want each time that you pull it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to add `date_default_timezone_set('TimeZone here');` so that it will return the correct date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `intval()` instead of `round()` change:

```
$minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
$years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
```

to

```
$minutes    = intval($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = intval($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = intval($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = intval($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = intval($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
$years      = intval($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
```

Comment: Yes.. the code does work as a hard-written format. Thatt isnt the issue. i need the date from my sql as the $currenttime. it will not read it without throwing an error. it should be automatic from the date of the post. THERE lies my issue..

Comment: How are you fetching the date from mysql? have you tried `echo $r->time;`

Comment: Yes i have. It loads on the page just fine... as the actual post date. but it doesnt display "time ago..." just raw post date. i need to get that into $currenttime without throwing an error....i have tried replacing the raw date with it... throws "unexpected 'echo" error....

Comment: Wait, what?  If your problem is getting the date from sql then we need to see your SQL query.

Comment: require '../db/connect_guest.php';
require '../db/security.php';


$records = array();

if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM guests ORDER BY id DESC")){

 if($results->num_rows){
  while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
   $records[] = $row;

  }
  
  $results->free();
 }
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($records), '</pre>';

Comment: if(!empty($_POST)){
  if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])){
   
   $name  = trim($_POST['name']);
   $email   = trim($_POST['email']);
   $message  = trim($_POST['message']);
   
   $time   = date("g:i A");
   $date   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   $ip   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
   
   
   if(!empty($name) && !empty($message)){
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO guests (name, email, message, date, time, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $insert->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $email, $message, $time, $date, $ip);
    
    if($insert->execute()){

Comment: Can you edit your original post and put all of that into a code box?  Easier to read...

Comment: Also, I suspect your unexpected echo is your `echo '<pre>', print_r($records), '</pre>';`  I don't think you can print_r within an echo statement, and you definitely do not concatenate with commas.  Probably better off with `echo '<pre>'; print_r($records); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Added both insert and Query to the codebox. both work flawlesly :)

Comment: Take a look at Line 95 of Codelobster3.php   Based on the error shown in your file, I'm guessing you have `date` and need `$date` (forgot the $)